# best practice to use dbghelp with your application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, dbghelp

I have a enterprise c++ application that I'd like to ship out and I do use the `dbghelp` library to get a stacktrace if my application crashes. What is the best practice for doing this?

My target users are windows10 and according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/dbghelp-versions), I should be okay to ship out the `dbghelp.dll` along with it?
"The redistribution policies for these included DLLs were specifically designed to make it as easy as possible for people to include these files in their own packages and releases."

Comment: Best practice: Don't gather a stack trace. Have the system collect a minidump instead. That way you have something *real* to diagnose the issue.

Comment: [Analyze crash dump files by using WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/crash-dump-files)